# Too big Image: OutOfMemory Exception

Tags: java, android, image, user-interface, android-fragments

My background image is too big, so the application crashes with the following error (I am copying other helpful messages from the LogCat as well)

```
01-10 14:53:48.799: E/dalvikvm-heap(9297): Out of memory on a 6955024-byte allocation.
01-10 14:53:48.799: I/dalvikvm(9297): "main" prio=5 tid=1 RUNNABLE
01-10 14:53:48.799: I/dalvikvm(9297):   | group="main" sCount=0 dsCount=0 obj=0x40a729a0 self=0x2a00bba8
01-10 14:53:48.799: I/dalvikvm(9297):   | sysTid=9297 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=apps handle=1073849308
01-10 14:53:48.812: I/dalvikvm(9297):   | state=R schedstat=( 38497557466 45560972992 4658 ) utm=3335 stm=514 core=0
01-10 14:53:48.840: I/dalvikvm(9297):   at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
01-10 14:53:48.840: I/dalvikvm(9297):   at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:502)
01-10 14:53:48.840: I/dalvikvm(9297):   at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:355)
01-10 14:53:48.840: I/dalvikvm(9297):   at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:785)
01-10 14:53:48.840: I/dalvikvm(9297):   at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1965)
01-10 14:53:48.840: I/dalvikvm(9297):   at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:601)
01-10 14:53:48.840: I/dalvikvm(9297):   at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:3330)
01-10 14:53:48.860: I/dalvikvm(9297):   at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:3259)
01-10 14:53:48.860: I/dalvikvm(9297):   at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:425)
01-10 14:53:48.860: I/dalvikvm(9297):   at android.widget.RelativeLayout.<init>(RelativeLayout.java:210)
01-10 14:53:48.860: I/dalvikvm(9297):   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
01-10 14:53:48.860: I/dalvikvm(9297):   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417)
01-10 14:53:48.860: I/dalvikvm(9297):   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:587)
01-10 14:53:48.860: I/dalvikvm(9297):   at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
01-10 14:53:48.860: I/dalvikvm(9297):   at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:660)
01-10 14:53:48.860: I/dalvikvm(9297):   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:685)
01-10 14:53:48.860: I/dalvikvm(9297):   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:466)
01-10 14:53:48.860: I/dalvikvm(9297):   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
01-10 14:53:48.860: I/dalvikvm(9297):   at com.xxx.xxx.InputFragment.onCreateView(InputFragment.java:70)
01-10 14:53:48.860: I/dalvikvm(9297):   at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1478)
01-10 14:53:48.860: I/dalvikvm(9297):   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:927)
01-10 14:53:48.860: I/dalvikvm(9297):   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1104)
01-10 14:53:48.860: I/dalvikvm(9297):   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1086)
01-10 14:53:48.860: I/dalvikvm(9297):   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentManager.java:1877)
01-10 14:53:48.860: I/dalvikvm(9297):   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:552)
01-10 14:53:48.860: I/dalvikvm(9297):   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1164)
01-10 14:53:48.860: I/dalvikvm(9297):   at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:5114)
01-10 14:53:48.860: I/dalvikvm(9297):   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2153)
01-10 14:53:48.860: I/dalvikvm(9297):   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
01-10 14:53:48.860: I/dalvikvm(9297):   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3692)
01-10 14:53:48.860: I/dalvikvm(9297):   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:141)
01-10 14:53:48.860: I/dalvikvm(9297):   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1240)
01-10 14:53:48.910: I/dalvikvm(9297):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-10 14:53:48.910: I/dalvikvm(9297):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-10 14:53:48.920: I/dalvikvm(9297):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
01-10 14:53:48.920: I/dalvikvm(9297):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-10 14:53:48.920: I/dalvikvm(9297):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-10 14:53:48.920: I/dalvikvm(9297):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
01-10 14:53:48.920: I/dalvikvm(9297):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
01-10 14:53:48.920: I/dalvikvm(9297):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-10 14:53:49.315: D/skia(9297): --- decoder->decode returned false
01-10 14:53:49.315: D/AndroidRuntime(9297): Shutting down VM
01-10 14:53:49.320: W/dalvikvm(9297): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a71930)
01-10 14:53:49.570: E/AndroidRuntime(9297): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-10 14:53:49.570: E/AndroidRuntime(9297): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.xxx.xxx/com.xxx.xxx.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class <unknown>
01-10 14:53:49.570: E/AndroidRuntime(9297):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
01-10 14:53:49.570: E/AndroidRuntime(9297):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
01-10 14:53:49.570: E/AndroidRuntime(9297):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3692)
01-10 14:53:49.570: E/AndroidRuntime(9297):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:141)
01-10 14:53:49.570: E/AndroidRuntime(9297):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1240)
01-10 14:53:49.570: E/AndroidRuntime(9297):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-10 14:53:49.570: E/AndroidRuntime(9297):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-10 14:53:49.570: E/AndroidRuntime(9297):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
01-10 14:53:49.570: E/AndroidRuntime(9297):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-10 14:53:49.570: E/AndroidRuntime(9297):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-10 14:53:49.570: E/AndroidRuntime(9297):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
01-10 14:53:49.570: E/AndroidRuntime(9297):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
01-10 14:53:49.570: E/AndroidRuntime(9297):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-10 14:53:49.570: E/AndroidRuntime(9297): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class <unknown>
01-10 14:53:49.570: E/AndroidRuntime(9297):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:613)
01-10 14:53:49.570: E/AndroidRuntime(9297):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
01-10 14:53:49.570: E/AndroidRuntime(9297):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:660)
01-10 14:53:49.570: E/AndroidRuntime(9297):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:685)
01-10 14:53:49.570: E/AndroidRuntime(9297):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:466)
01-10 14:53:49.570: E/AndroidRuntime(9297):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
01-10 14:53:49.570: E/AndroidRuntime(9297):     at com.xxx.xxx.InputFragment.onCreateView(InputFragment.java:70)
01-10 14:53:49.570: E/AndroidRuntime(9297):     at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1478)
01-10 14:53:49.570: E/AndroidRuntime(9297):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:927)
01-10 14:53:49.570: E/AndroidRuntime(9297):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1104)
01-10 14:53:49.570: E/AndroidRuntime(9297):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1086)
01-10 14:53:49.570: E/AndroidRuntime(9297):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentManager.java:1877)
01-10 14:53:49.570: E/AndroidRuntime(9297):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:552)
01-10 14:53:49.570: E/AndroidRuntime(9297):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1164)
01-10 14:53:49.570: E/AndroidRuntime(9297):     at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:5114)
01-10 14:53:49.570: E/AndroidRuntime(9297):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2153)
01-10 14:53:49.570: E/AndroidRuntime(9297):     ... 12 more
01-10 14:53:49.570: E/AndroidRuntime(9297): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
01-10 14:53:49.570: E/AndroidRuntime(9297):     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
01-10 14:53:49.570: E/AndroidRuntime(9297):     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417)
01-10 14:53:49.570: E/AndroidRuntime(9297):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:587)
01-10 14:53:49.570: E/AndroidRuntime(9297):     ... 27 more
01-10 14:53:49.570: E/AndroidRuntime(9297): Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
01-10 14:53:49.570: E/AndroidRuntime(9297):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
01-10 14:53:49.570: E/AndroidRuntime(9297):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:502)
01-10 14:53:49.570: E/AndroidRuntime(9297):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:355)
01-10 14:53:49.570: E/AndroidRuntime(9297):     at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:785)
01-10 14:53:49.570: E/AndroidRuntime(9297):     at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1965)
01-10 14:53:49.570: E/AndroidRuntime(9297):     at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:601)
01-10 14:53:49.570: E/AndroidRuntime(9297):     at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:3330)
01-10 14:53:49.570: E/AndroidRuntime(9297):     at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:3259)
01-10 14:53:49.570: E/AndroidRuntime(9297):     at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:425)
01-10 14:53:49.570: E/AndroidRuntime(9297):     at android.widget.RelativeLayout.<init>(RelativeLayout.java:210)
01-10 14:53:49.570: E/AndroidRuntime(9297):     ... 30 more
```

My background image is in Drawable folders. Yes, I meant "folders" because the application is designed to support multiple screens and images are in all folders, with slight change of sizes.

How can I load this large bitmaps without an issue? I went through the following code.

```
public static Bitmap getResizedBitmap(Bitmap image, int newHeight, int newWidth) {
    int width = image.getWidth();
    int height = image.getHeight();
    float scaleWidth = ((float) newWidth) / width;
    float scaleHeight = ((float) newHeight) / height;
    // create a matrix for the manipulation
    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
    // resize the bit map
    matrix.postScale(scaleWidth, scaleHeight);
    // recreate the new Bitmap
    Bitmap resizedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(image, 0, 0, width, height,
            matrix, false);
    return resizedBitmap;
}
```

But the case is, this code set the width and height manually, right? But I am going to apply this image as the background image, so I don't know whether this is the best way, and I am not sure what value to insert as width and height. All I know is I need to set the image in `onCreateView()` method (I am using fragments).

Comment: Have you tried to alloc 7 gigabytes of memory?  Does it fit with the memory settings with which you started your JVM?

Comment: I'm not sure you're using the right constructor for `resizedBitmap`.  You don't need a `Matrix` for simple resizing.  Consider this constructor: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#createBitmap(android.graphics.Bitmap, int, int, int, int)

Comment: What resolution your image have?

Comment: @Hellboy: Hi, it is 72

Comment: @FlowOverStack 72x72px?

Comment: @Hellboy: I am not good at graphics, I dnt know anything about it. That is the value provided by photoshop, when I open the dialog box called 'Image Resize'

Comment: @FlowOverStack im asking how many pixels that image have in width and height. You can check it in image properties

Comment: @Hellboy: Please provide your comment about resolution as an answer. I reduced the resolution from 72 to 35 using photoshop 'resolution' field in 'Image Resize' window.

Answer (score 1):

Use BitmapFactory.Options to get the size of the image before loading it, then you can scale the background down to a lower resolution image, if needed, that still fits the background but doesn't throw an OOM error.  Also, you can use the DisplayMetrics for your required width and height, or the width and height of the view whose background you are setting.

From the android training documation (http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html):

> The BitmapFactory class provides several decoding methods
>   (decodeByteArray(), decodeFile(), decodeResource(), etc.) for creating
>   a Bitmap from various sources. Choose the most appropriate decode
>   method based on your image data source. These methods attempt to
>   allocate memory for the constructed bitmap and therefore can easily
>   result in an OutOfMemory exception. Each type of decode method has
>   additional signatures that let you specify decoding options via the
>   BitmapFactory.Options class. Setting the inJustDecodeBounds property
>   to true while decoding avoids memory allocation, returning null for
>   the bitmap object but setting outWidth, outHeight and outMimeType.
>   This technique allows you to read the dimensions and type of the image
>   data prior to construction (and memory allocation) of the bitmap.

```
 BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
 options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
 BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.id.myimage, options);
 int imageHeight = options.outHeight; 
 int imageWidth = options.outWidth; 
 String imageType = options.outMimeType;
```

> To avoid java.lang.OutOfMemory exceptions, check the dimensions of a
>   bitmap before decoding it, unless you absolutely trust the source to
>   provide you with predictably sized image data that comfortably fits
>   within the available memory.

Answer (score 0):

You need to either allocate more heap to your JVM (`-Xmx7g`) or tile the image so that you don't need to hold the whole thing in memory at once.
 The tiling is only useful of course if you aren't showing the whole image at once.  If you are the to manage this you could compress the image in some way prior to trying to load it.
There's also, third party libraries such as [DiscMemImage](http://code.google.com/p/jaitools/wiki/DiskMemImage) to use images while limiting memory usage.